# Android display error dialog onError method

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I want to display the error dialog box returned from api, on handler result  but I get nothing while trying to display. I would help on displaying this error

```
 @Override
 public void onError(Throwable e) {
     TicketScanActivity.this.dialogProgress.dismiss();
     showValidErrorDialog(getApplicationContext());
     Log.d("onError", e.toString());
 }
```

this is the show method I am calling to display message

```
private void showValidErrorDialog(Context context)
{
    new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
            .title(R.string.dialog_error)
            .content(R.string.unsuccessful_validation)
            .positiveText(R.string.dialog_positive)
            .show();
}
```

Comment: And if you do this **showValidErrorDialog(TicketScanActivity.this);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `getApplicationContext()` to show a dialog box.

Dialog is owned by his activity. Use the current activity context instead using the application context.

Try use `this`, `TicketScanActivity.this`, `getContext()` or `getActivity()`. It will depend where you are building the dialog box.

Comment: i used this one TicketScanActivity.this and it worked